# Can this casue any Issue ::SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter - Concurrency count 25 has reached limit 25 – blocking

Tags: spring

We are creating `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` using spring dependency injection. But at some point of time we get the above error and we are not able to proceed further.

Any idea that could be issue in this case?

Comment: Hi, you need to show the code which you have written, so that SO users can try to replicate your issue. Please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what is the concurrent limit set ? .try setting SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.UNBOUNDED_CONCURRENCY or NO_CONCURRENCY

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not explaining the question completely.But i have identified the problem. The code written was crap thats why i didn't posted. 
Lets assume we as processing Families(Just for illustrations). And all the families details. 
Lets Say ThreadConcurrency set to 25. We assigned 100 families to process to our SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. Same thread pool was being used to process details of families also.
So what was happening all the threads were taken by header level(Families) and not threads were left for processing of details. SO a kind of deadlock happened. As to proceed further details need thread but all the threads were already taken by families(at header level) so header won't release thread until its work is nit complete but how will header release thread as it is wait for its details to complete.

I am not a good writer.